# HttpContext and AutoComplete Extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AutoComplete Extender from Ajax control tool kit.
I have a webservice that this extender uses.  In the web method I need to access a value `empid` which is present in my ASPX page.  I placed this value in `HttpContext's` Items collection in my ASPX page.

```
HttpContext.Items["empid"]=<value>;
```

In the web method I am trying to access the same using

```
string s=Context.Items["empid"];
```

But Items collection does not have any item there.  Is this due to the partial postback the autocomplete extender control is doing.

Can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

The AutoComplete Extender uses a web method with a specific signature (explained in the documentation) on a web service. This will be called from the browser using JavaScript (behind the scenes).

The web service and its web method know nothing about your page - they only know the information that is passed to them in the arguments of the web method.

Comment: Thanks Richard for the response.  However I still have a doubt.  I am able to access the Cache object in this web method.  I am using it as below
Context.Cache["key"].  And I am curious to know how this works then?

Comment: Calling Context.Cache["key"] will simply return null if no item called "key" exists, so I think that's what you're seeing.

Comment: No Richard I am getting proper values in Context.Cache["key"].  Actually I added Cache["somekey"]=value and HttpContext.Items["empid"]=value during page_init event.  I am getting proper values when I access Context.Cache in web method but when I try accessing Items I dont get them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean Deepa - however from a design point of view I would say that the web method should not rely on data in your cache, unless it put the data there itself.

Comment: Here's my design.  The autocomplete extender is using a web method.  This web method is searching strings from a cache object which is already populated.  Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: Also coming to my doubt now, you said the web method know nothing about my page which is why it does not know Context.items["key"] and which is why I get null in web method.  However i observed that it knows Context.Cache["key"] and give me proper value there but not for Context.Items[] .Thoughts?

Comment: What are you caching, and why? If you are caching for performance reasons, have you proven that you actually have a performance issue and that it is resolved by caching?

Comment: Yes that's right we have performance issues and which is why we are caching.

Comment: I think you need to store your cached data in your database in a rapid-to-query form, and access it from your web service call. I'm assuming that you have a database query that is your bottleneck...